# Xpath for an element with span only(no or or anything) and that too with similar attributes and only difference in text

Tags: c#, html, xml, selenium, xpath

I am trying to get an xpath for this button element with text 'Cancel'.

```
<div class="uipresk">
    <button class="something" role="button" type="button">
        <span class="thisthing">OK</span>
    </button>
    <button class="something" role="button" type="button">
        <span class="thisthing">Cancel</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I have tried 
`//span[@class='thisthing' and text()='Cancel']` and it says "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

I have tried various other xpaths and none of them have helped.

This is inside a nested iframe. I did confirm I have switched to the required iframe because it identified an element in a sibling div but it had an id and that’s why probably it worked. But the Cancel button is not working at all.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Thanks

Comment: Please show the code and the stack trace.  The XPath expression looks good to me.

Comment: How many attributes do you have in each span?

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways you can do this. The problem is you are not clicking a button. You are clicking a span. These both work.

```
 //div[@class='uipresk']//button[1]
 //div[@class='uipresk']//button[2]

 //button/span[contains(text(), 'OK')]
 //button/span[contains(text(), 'Cancel')]
```

Added text to test so the buttons went somewhere..

```
<div class="uipresk">
<button class="something" role="button" type="button" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.cnn.com';">
    <span class="thisthing">OK</span>
</button>
<button class="something" role="button" type="button" onclick="location.href = 'http://www.cnn.com';">
    <span class="thisthing">Cancel</span>
</button>
```

Comment: It threw the same exception for this one too. Is there anything else you suggest i check?  Thanks

Comment: give me 5 minutes - loading to visual studio

Comment: ok just tested //div[@class='uipresk']//button[1] and it works fine on my tests. I added some additional code so the link would go somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure you have switched to the iframe successfully?

Comment: Yes. I made sure by selecting a dropdown menu  value in the same iframe. and the script selected the value succesfully. It is a nested iframe. I used driver.SwitchTo.Frame(name1).SwitchTo().Frame(name2). SwitchTo().Frame(name3).       I am using PageObjectModel, just for info

Comment: I would create separate methods for each. driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName1); driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName2); driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frameName3);    driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();